# Turn off assembly signing and other visual studio global defaults

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I recently opened in Visual Studio 2017 a solution with assembly signing turned on for all of its projects. Now, any solution I open has assembly signing turned on for all the projects with the key file from that other solution. I even installed the 2019 Preview and it's doing the same thing. It appears that a default setting has been flipped somewhere. How can I turn this off?

Bonus points if you can tell me how to remove my new default code style rules that are also applied to all solutions since opening that one solution several days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a .build.props file in C:\ from building that solution. All versions of Visual Studio were detecting the code style and assembly signing configuration in that file. Removing it has fixed my problem.